# How to install a Flatpickr plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, flatpickr

I'm starting to use [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) (moving from [xdsoft datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker), which seems no longer actively maintained) and would like to achieve scrolling behavior just like xdsoft's datetimepicker had, i.e. allowing scrolling between months with the mouse scroll wheel.

I see on https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/pull/1192 that the functionality used to be there in the past, but that it was removed.
On the [plugins repo](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/tree/master/src/plugins), I see a `scrollPlugin.ts` which I assume is what I'm looking for.

However I cannot find in [the docs](https://flatpickr.js.org/plugins/) how to install this plugin.

I'm not using NPM or so but am loading the flatpickr js/css files directly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/flatpickr/material_blue.css">
<script src="/static/flatpickr/flatpickr.js"></script>
```

What is the proper way to install a TS plugin? Assuming TS stands for Typescript, do I need to transform it to JS and if so how?

Using Flatpickr 4.6.9 (latest one as time of writing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to include the plugin file

like

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@4.6.9/dist/plugins/scrollPlugin.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For whoever is looking for the plugins JS files, I've found them through [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/browse/flatpickr@4.6.13/dist/plugins/)/[JSDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/flatpickr?path=dist%2Fplugins).

Just include them as any other CSS or JS.